# Equivalence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

[image]

Having trouble proving this is an equivalence relation.

Is it suffice to say that let $x y z$ be any string in $\Sigma^*$,

$(xz \in L \iff yz \in L) \rightarrow (yz \in L \iff xz \in L)$ shows that $xRy \rightarrow yRx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in \Sigma^*$, define $L(x)$ to be the language $\{z\in \Sigma^*\mid xz\in L\}$.  Then the definition of $R$ can be rephrased as
$$xRy \iff L(x)=L(y).$$
This is clearly reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, but assuming this is an elementary course you probably want to at least write out transitivity, making clear you understand why $xRy$ and $yRz$ imply $xRz$.

Answer (score 0):

The specific situation of formal languages is unnecessary.

Suppose there is a relation called "?".  Given $x$, define $??(x)$ be the set of $u$ such that $x?u$.  Let $???$ be the relation "has the same value of ?? as", so that $a???b$ when $??(a)=??(b)$.  Then ??? is clearly an equivalence relation.  That's all that is going on here, for a particular choice of $?$.

Comment: So in the context of the original question, how would I provide a formal proof? Is what I provided enough

Comment: I only looked carefully at the problem statement, not your argument.  The formal proof I had in mind is to apply the ??? thing to the case where $a?b$ means $ab \in L$.

Comment: Thanks! So in essence could I just say that xRy when xz is in L and yz is in L?

Comment: (or both not in L).

Comment: and that implies yRx?